# How to change filename on the fly depending on the title args - nginx rewrite

Tags: nginx, rewrite

i am serving `.pdf` files using nginx web server. and setting filename of `.pdf` file using rewrite rule , depending on the `title args`.

what i am trying to do is, add my domain name `example.com` in the filename

**1. if `title` var contains `example.com` in it then use `title` var data for filename.**

e.g.

```
URL : http://example.com/pdf/0D2E8C9DC2F732A6ACC6150811515F697E3C376C.pdf?title=[example.com]ebook
Filename : [example.com]ebook.pdf
```

**2. if `title` var does not contains `example.com` in it then make filename as `[example.com]title var.pdf`**

e.g.

```
URL : http://example.com/pdf/0D2E8C9DC2F732A6ACC6150811515F697E3C376C.pdf?title=ebook
Filename : [example.com]ebook.pdf
```

**3. if title is not set then use filename as `[example.com]hash.pdf` filename.**

e.g.

```
URL : http://example.com/pdf/0D2E8C9DC2F732A6ACC6150811515F697E3C376C.pdf
Filename : [example.com]0D2E8C9DC2F732A6ACC6150811515F697E3C376C.pdf
```

How can i achieve something like this. ?

---

my current config looks like this

```
#pdf download block
location ~* /pdf/([0-9a-fA-F])([0-9a-fA-F])([0-9a-fA-F])([0-9a-fA-F])([0-9a-fA-F])([0-9a-fA-F]+)\.pdf$ {

#if title is not set then use hash.pdf as filename
if ( $arg_title  = '' ) {
    add_header Content-Disposition 'attachment; filename="[example.com]$1$2$3$4$5$6.pdf"';
}

add_header Content-Disposition 'attachment; filename="[example.com]$arg_title.pdf"';
alias   /var/www/example.com/pdf/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$1$2$3$4$5$6.pdf;
expires 1y;
}
```

above code works fine only if title var is not set at all, but if i set title var as `[example.com]ebook.pdf` it adds domain name one more time and the final filename becomes

```
[example.com][example.com]ebook.pdf
```

Comment: Your question is really difficult to understand. Please restate what you're trying to achieve, both big picture (ie what are you trying to achieve and why) and details, such as what the "title" you're referring to is.

Comment: @tim sorry for my bad english, i have updated the question., thanks

Comment: Are you trying to build a semi-secure e-book delivery system using a reverse proxy? Have you considered using a product made to do what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: nope. i am just trying to serve files using nginx rewrite and setting file name depending the title variable in the url.

Comment: Looks like a regular expression problem, maybe you should add that tag. I can't help but good luck :)

Comment: do you want to serve changed filenames from disk, or do you want keep disk location same and want to have downloaded filename changed?

Comment: @AndreiMikhaltsov Downloaded filename changed. so it stores on user PC so it can remember where it downloaded from.

Comment: What you're trying to do is bad from the usability perspective -- with ***attachment*** as `Content-Disposition` you're ***forcing people to download your PDF*** -- users will have find a location and name for it, and then bother finding a programme to view it in.  I don't download any PDFs personally.  If the browser doesn't let me view a PDF, I go to the next one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I understood, we can assume that if there is an `[example.com]` substring in the beginning of the `$arg_title` variable, we can just safely cut it out. 
So here is the config that you need:

```
location ~* /pdf/([0-9a-fA-F])([0-9a-fA-F])([0-9a-fA-F])([0-9a-fA-F])([0-9a-fA-F])([0-9a-fA-F]+)\.pdf$ {

 #First of all we should put pdf path from the request into a variable,
 #since $1,$2,$n would contain other data later:
set $hashpath $1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$1$2$3$4$5$6;

 #Same applies to hash title:
set $hashtitle $1$2$3$4$5$6;

 #Now we try to get the title argument without getting [example.com] in the beginning:
if ( $arg_title ~ "^(\[example\.com\])?(.*)$")
{
   #This way if title contained [example.com], it would go to $1 variable, while $2 has our new cleaned title:
  set $pdftitle $2;
}

 #now we check if title was empty:
if ( $arg_title  = '' ) {
 #and assign our title that $hashtitle variable we got from the request earlier:
    set $pdftitle $hashtitle;
}

 #also we check if title has only [example.com] without anything else:
if ( $arg_title  = '[example.com]' ) {
    set $pdftitle $hashtitle;
}

 #After that we can safely put [example.com] in front of our filename, without worrying that there would be a double:
add_header Content-Disposition 'attachment; filename="[example.com]$pdftitle.pdf"';

alias /var/www/example.com/pdf/$hashpath.pdf;
expires 1y;
}
```

Works fine with nginx 1.9.12 here:

[title=[example.com]test](http://pstbin.ru/pdf/0D2E8C9DC2F732A6ACC6150811515F697E3C376C.pdf?title=[example.com]test)

[title=just_test](http://pstbin.ru/pdf/0D2E8C9DC2F732A6ACC6150811515F697E3C376C.pdf?title=just_test)

[title is not set](http://pstbin.ru/pdf/0D2E8C9DC2F732A6ACC6150811515F697E3C376C.pdf)

with actual file located [here](http://pstbin.ru/pdf/0/D/2/E/8/0D2E8C9DC2F732A6ACC6150811515F697E3C376C.pdf)

Comment: thanks for your answer, my files location on HDD is like alias   /var/www/example.com/pdf/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$1$2$3$4$5$6.pdf;

Comment: I've updated my answer for your particular environment!